# Align h5 and Social Media Icon

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add sharing functionality in my footer. However, the icon (which has a link to IG) is appearing below an h5. How would I get the icon and the h5 to be on the same line?

Here is my HTML and CSS:

```css
footer {
  background-color: black;
  line-height: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-top: 2px solid #f28600;
  text-align: center;
}

footer h5 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
}

footer a img {
  height: 25%
}
```

```html
<footer> 
 <h5> © 2019 The Novel Column </h4>
 <a href="http://www.instagram.com"> <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-messaging-ui-color-shapes-2-free/128/social-instagram-new-circle-512.png"> </a> 
</footer>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

With the propriety `display:flex` you can put two elements on the same line.

```css
footer {

  background-color: black;
   line-height: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-top: 2px solid #f28600;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;

}

footer h5 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;

}
```

```html
<footer> 

 <h5> © 2019 The Novel Column </h4>

 <a href="http://www.instagram.com"> 
  <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-messaging-ui-color-shapes-2-free/128/social-instagram-new-circle-512.png" width="20px"> </a> 

 


</footer>
```

You can use the propriety `justify-content` depends on what your trying to do.

[image: justify-content exemple]

---

### Reference

> [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)